# Nokogiri: Select content between element A and B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom, parsing, nokogiri

What's the smartest way to have Nokogiri select all content between the start and the stop element (including start-/stop-element)?

Check example code below to understand what I'm looking for:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

value = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-HTML_END)
  "<html>
    <body>
      <p id='para-1'>A</p>
      <div class='block' id='X1'>
        <p class="this">Foo</p>
        <p id='para-2'>B</p>
      </div>
      <p id='para-3'>C</p>
      <p class="that">Bar</p>
      <p id='para-4'>D</p>
      <p id='para-5'>E</p>
      <div class='block' id='X2'>
        <p id='para-6'>F</p>
      </div>
      <p id='para-7'>F</p>
      <p id='para-8'>G</p>
    </body>
  </html>"
HTML_END

parent = value.css('body').first

# START element
@start_element = parent.at('p#para-3')
# STOP element
@end_element = parent.at('p#para-7')
```

**The result (return value) should look like this**:

```
<p id='para-3'>C</p>
<p class="that">Bar</p>
<p id='para-4'>D</p>
<p id='para-5'>E</p>
<div class='block' id='X2'>
  <p id='para-6'>F</p>
</div>
<p id='para-7'>F</p>
```

**Update: This is my current solution, though I think there must be something smarter:**

```
@my_content = ""
@selected_node = true

def collect_content(_start)

  if _start == @end_element
    @my_content << _start.to_html
    @selected_node = false
  end

  if @selected_node == true
    @my_content << _start.to_html
    collect_content(_start.next)
  end

end

collect_content(@start_element)

puts @my_content
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A way-too-smart oneliner which uses recursion:

```
def collect_between(first, last)
  first == last ? [first] : [first, *collect_between(first.next, last)]
end
```

An iterative solution:

```
def collect_between(first, last)
  result = [first]
  until first == last
    first = first.next
    result << first
  end
  result
end
```

**EDIT: (Short) explanation of the asterix**

It's called the splat operator. It "unrolls" an array:

```
array = [3, 2, 1]
[4, array]  # => [4, [3, 2, 1]]
[4, *array] # => [4, 3, 2, 1]

some_method(array)  # => some_method([3, 2, 1])
some_method(*array) # => some_method(3, 2, 1)

def other_method(*array); array; end
other_method(1, 2, 3) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions and thanks for your über-smart recursive one-liner! Though, I don't understand what the '*' before the recursive call of collect_between() stands for. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I've added a tiny explanation in my orginal answer. Google around for "splat operator" for more :-)

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity: Do you have any idea where the "splat operator" is documented? Couldn't find a word in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/

Comment: ...and googling around for '*' definitively makes no sense. ;-)

Comment: the one liner worked locally for me, but not on a server for some reason. Mike's answer below direct from the now included Nokogiri function worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

```
# monkeypatches for Nokogiri::NodeSet
# note: versions of these functions will be in Nokogiri 1.3
class Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
  unless method_defined?(:index)
    def index(node)
      each_with_index { |member, j| return j if member == node }
    end
  end

  unless method_defined?(:slice)
    def slice(start, length)
      new_set = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(self.document)
      length.times { |offset| new_set << self[start + offset] }
      new_set
    end
  end
end

#
#  solution #1: picking elements out of node children
#  NOTE that this will also include whitespacy text nodes between the <p> elements.
#
possible_matches = parent.children
start_index = possible_matches.index(@start_element)
stop_index = possible_matches.index(@end_element)
answer_1 = possible_matches.slice(start_index, stop_index - start_index + 1)

#
#  solution #2: picking elements out of a NodeSet
#  this will only include elements, not text nodes.
#
possible_matches = value.xpath("//body/*")
start_index = possible_matches.index(@start_element)
stop_index = possible_matches.index(@end_element)
answer_2 = possible_matches.slice(start_index, stop_index - start_index + 1)
```

Comment: ...i'm really looking forward to nokogiri 1.3. :)

Comment: please note that NodeSet#slice and NodeSet#index are now in Nokogiri master on github. these will be in the 1.3.0 release later this month.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness a **XPath only** solution :)
It builds an intersection of two sets, the following siblings of the start element and the preceding siblings of the end element.

> *Basically you can build an intersection with:*
>
> ```
>   $a[count(.|$b) = count($b)]
> ```

A little divided on variables for readability:

```
@start_element = "//p[@id='para-3']"
@end_element = "//p[@id='para-7']"
@set_a = "#@start_element/following-sibling::*"
@set_b = "#@end_element/preceding-sibling::*"

@my_content = value.xpath("#@set_a[ count(.|#@set_b) = count(#@set_b) ]
                         | #@start_element | #@end_element")
```

Siblings don't include the element itself, so the start and end elements must be included in the expression separately.

**Edit:** Easier solution:

```
@start_element = "p[@id='para-3']"
@end_element = "p[@id='para-7']"
@my_content = value.xpath("//*[preceding-sibling::#@start_element and
                               following-sibling::#@end_element]
                         | //#@start_element | //#@end_element")
```