# Why does my extracted/scraped HTML code render as text?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I want to extract the search form, from [this webpage](http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc), and render it on the "static_pages/home" page of my Rails app: [Codepen Example of "static_pages/home"](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jzGbK?editors=100)

Steps taken:

1. I created the following Ruby script to verify that I could actually extract the form:

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'
   require 'open-uri'

   url = 'http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc'
   data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

   form = data.xpath('//form[@action="http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc"]')
   puts form
   ```
2. Shifting over to Rails, I included Nokogiri and OpenURI in my gem file and used bundle to install the gems.
3. I created a StaticPages controller:

   ```
   class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
     require 'nokogiri'
     require 'open-uri'

     url = 'http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc'
     data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
     @form = data.xpath('//form[@action="http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc"]')
    end
   end
   ```
4. And an accompanying view:

   ```
   <h1>StaticPages#home</h1>
   <p>Find me in app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb</p>
   <%= @form %>
   ```

The HTML code is successfully extracted but it is rendered [as text](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzqrb?editors=100) instead of HTML. It seems like either:

```
@form = data.xpath('//form[@action="http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc"]')
```

or

```
<%= @form %>
```

converts the extracted HTML to text. How can I insert the HTML content I have extracted as HTML and not as text?

My research has suggested using [Net:HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217223/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-webpage-in-ruby).

Comment: Isn't it because Rails automatically escape html code in `<%= @form %>`, right? How about using like `<%= @form.html_safe %>`? (Sorry I don't know very proper way to write it in your Rails version)

Comment: This will help you https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/28/ruby-on-rails-why-do-we-need-to-html_safe-string-why-html-tags-not-rendered/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply putting `<%= @form.html_safe %>`, in the view will return an error. This is because `@form` is formatted as text, not as HTML.
To correct this:

1. go to the Static Pages controller and change:

   ```
   @form = data.xpath('//form[@action="http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc"]')
   ```

   to
       @form = data.xpath('//form[@action="http://websoc.reg.uci.edu/perl/WebSoc"]').to_html.
2. Now `@form` stores the HTML as HTML, instead of text. To render this in the view, we need to change:

   ```
   <%= @form %>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <%= @form.html_safe %>
   ```

By default, Rails will convert `<%= @form %>` to text as a security precaution; you do not want malicious code embedded into your page. By declaring `@form.html_safe` we tell Rails that the HTML content is intended and, therefore safe. This allows the contents of `@form` to render in the view as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your question stated that you get text while it was `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`.

"[How do I scrape HTML between two HTML comments using Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869004/how-do-i-scrape-html-between-two-html-comments-using-nokogiri)" is a similar question for scrapping the Nodes. Once you get the string `html_string`, you may use `html_string.html_safe`.

Comment: it returns an error:"undefined method `html_safe' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x4079d30>"